# How to insert multiple times

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, html-framework-7

I insert new data from input to my sql table (customers) , this is ok
, but when I try to insert the other data second times , it's start to insert multiple time, is that I have any loop error when i reappend my table?

```
$$(document).on('click', '#add_products', function() {

            var new_name = $$(document).find('#new_name').val();
            var new_phone = $$(document).find('#new_phone').val();
            var new_order = $$(document).find('#new_order').val();



            //' " + new_name + " ',' " + new_phone + " ' ,' " + new_order + " '
            var sqlpost = "INSERT INTO customers (name, telephone, order_num) VALUES (' " + new_name + " ',' " + new_phone + " ' ,' " + new_order + " ')";

            connection.query(sqlpost, function(err, result) {


                app.dialog.alert('Successfull insert!');

                $$(document).find('#employee_table').empty();
                var sqlget = 'SELECT * FROM `customers`';


                connection.query(sqlget, function(error, results, fields) {

                    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                        $$(document).find('#employee_table').append($$('<tr> ' +
                            ' <td class="label-cell"> ' + results[i].name + ' </td>' +
                            ' <td class="numeric-cell">' + results[i].telephone + '</td> ' +
                            ' <td class="numeric-cell">' + results[i].order_num + '</td> ' +
                            '<td class="numeric-cell">' + results[i].date + '</td> ' +
                            '</tr>'));
                        console.log(i);
                    }
                });
            });
            app.views.main.router.navigate('/home_employee/');

        })
    })
```

insert first data is okay
the second data will insert to table *2
the third data will insert *3

etc..

I am a rookie and i read whole documentation , maybe there is answer inside it but I am still learning

I keep changing the loop condition to get what I want but fail

every data just only need to be input once

Comment: `$$(document)` ?? `$$` ??

Comment: This line `$$(document).on('click', '#add_products', function() {` is duplicated? Is that in the real code? ___That may well explain your issue___

Comment: The first time the CLICK handler runs. It registers another CLICK handler. So the second time you Click you run **2** click handlers and therefore do everything twice

Comment: sorry typo at here , my code have only one $$(document).on('click', '#add_products', function() {

Comment: just edit it , is that I need to check my loop?

Comment: the reason I use $$ is because I am using framework7

Comment: Is it inserting multiple times in db? or just showing multiple rows on your UI?

Comment: Please share the html of `#employee_table`, I doubt your `empty` statement is not working here.

Comment: it is inserting multiple times to db , i found 2 problems , first is framework 7 i page init whole page and when the page redirect back to this html , the code will all fire again.. second is $$('#add_products').on('click', function() { work very well

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Framework7 that well, but just a shot in the dark. Do you get the same result if you change to

```
$$('#add_products').on('click', function() {
```

Also are you sure that the data is stored to database multiple times so that it's not just some issue with emptying the table, as Shaharyar said.

Comment: OMGGGGGGGGGGG THANKS!!!! this work!!

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer if it is.

Answer (score 1):

Remove one of the on click events maybe?

```
$$(document).on('click', '#add_products', function() {
    $$(document).on('click', '#add_products', function() {
```

I guess that each time you press the element with id "add_product" you will trigger the functionality inside. That is to register a new click event.

```js
var num = 0
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){
    num += 1;
    console.log(num);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn"> Click me </button>
```

Comment: Please explain this answer.

Comment: typo , my code only have one $$(document).on('click', '#add_products', function() {